# WordPress site not displaying some content on client side

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a WordPress site hosted on a home server. On the WordPress site, I have managed to upload a purchased template and import sample content. This means that the website should display exactly like the demo. From WordPress, when I view the website from the local machine (the home server), It displays all of the content that I uploaded. But when I connect to the website from any client, the backgrounds displays, but not the images. I used a plugin called cherryframework4.

http://74.208.12.48/index.php  that is the link to the site... in looking at the console logs, I can see that most files filed to load. but all the files exist are in the directories.

it is also worth mentioning that i used cherrframework4 as a plugin to install the site

Comment: View the page source and check the URLs for the images.  WordPress usually uses full URLs (including the server name), so if you uploaded them locally, they may have (say) `localhost` instead of the domain name, and be unreachable from the client.

Comment: It'd help if you could provide a link to your site.  Otherwise, open the site in (say) Chrome, open the developer tools, and look in the console for error messages.  Edit your question to include them - they may help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Happens regularly when moving from localhost to live site or from temporary URL to live. It's looking for images on the initial build platform (e.g. your machine or temporary URL) rather than from the live server:

- It's looking for: localhost:8888/path-to-image/image.jpg
- Should be looking for: domainname.com/path-to-image/image.jpg

Try using the [search and replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) to search for instances of localhost:8888 (or whatever your machine is called) and replace it with the live domain name.

Be careful to check the URL in the code to extract and change only the part of the string that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Settings>general I changed the WordPress address and the site URL address to the ip address of my server. What has happening was that, because the url was set to http://localhost, the client machine was looking for the images in its own drive.